# How to validate local-date in malli schema?

Tags: clojure, schema, malli

How to validate date in malli schema?
What is the data type that I must use?

I checked with local-date, but its not valid in clojure.
This is the code I followed.

```
(def date (m/schema [:map
                   [:a :int]
                   [:b :re #"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"]
                   ]))
```

Thsi worked fine when I validated.

```
(m/validate s2 {:a 1 :b "2022-07-28"})
=> true
```

But when I try to convert this to Json schema, I get error as such.

```
(def s2 [:map 
         [:orderId string?]
         [:OrderDate :re "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"]
         ])
Syntax error reading source at (REPL:3:24).
Unsupported escape character: \d
```

So how must in resolve this?
Edit : Reslved. Use it as

```
:re #"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}" OR [:re "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"]
```

But now validation fails :

```
(m/validate s2 {:a 1 :b "2022-07-28"})
=> false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

Dependency: `[metosin/malli "0.8.9"]`

Require: `[malli.json-schema :as json-schema]`

```
(json-schema/transform [:map
                        [:order-id :string]
                        [:order-date [:re #"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"]]])
=>
{:type "object",
 :properties {:order-id {:type "string"}, :order-date {:type "string", :pattern #"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"}},
 :required [:order-id :order-date]}
```

You can also take a look at a [pull request](https://github.com/metosin/malli/pull/545) aiming to add `java.time` dates into Malli, maybe you'll find something useful here.

Comment: Yes this works. And this too :
(def s2 [:map
         [:acctId string?]
         [:date :re #"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"]
         ])

But validation fails: 
(m/validate s2 {:a 1 :b "2022-07-28"})
=> false

Comment: It seems that keys in the map must have exactly these names (and your map also contains `int` instead of `string`), so here is an example that returns true: `(def s2 [:map [:acctId string?] [:date :re #"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"]])` `(m/validate s2 {:acctId "1" :date "2022-07-28"})`

Comment: This works! The problem was here : (and your map also contains int instead of string)